# Applying styles based on certain strings of text that have been run through HTMLEditFormat()

Tags: jquery, css, sql, coldfusion

I'm creating some simple chat and comment systems.

By the time users can read the comment text, it has already been run through a combination of `HTMLEditFormat()` and `ParagraphFormat()` in order to stop HTML from rendering while also preserving natural line breaks.

But now, I want to add some features based on the content of what the user types. For example, typing:

```
/me smashes his computer screen while trying to figure something out.
```

Would appear as:

***TRose smashes his computer screen while trying to figure something out.***

Looking for suggestions on how to handle this. Could I be using a different function to sanitize the comments initially?

Maybe even a jQuery function that can apply changes to text strings on page load?

Comment: ColdFusion does have a replace function.

Comment: You know, usually just the act of asking a question on SO makes me think critically and do the obvious thing. This is not one of those times. I can replace '/me' with a username and use JQuery after that... I thank you.

Comment: It's called the Law of Maximum Embarrassment and is not restricted to the internet.